# Matching words & partial colon-delimited words within parentheses (excluding parentheses)

Tags: regex

I am trying to extract stock symbols from a body of text. These matches usually come in the following forms:

```
(<symbol>) => (VOO)
(<market>:<symbol>) => (NASDAQ:C)
```

In the sample cases shown above, I'd like to match VOO and C, skipping everything else. This regex gets me halfway there:

```
(?<=\()(.*?)(?=\))
```

With this, I match what's included within the parentheses, but the logic that ignores "noise" like `NASDAQ:` eludes me. I'd love to learn how to conditionally specify this pattern/logic.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Try `[^():]+(?=\))`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/9mZCH7/1).

Comment: Or, capture it like this into Group 1: `\((?:[^():]*:)?([^():]+)\)` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/bH1ALk/1)). Where are you doing this?

Comment: Thank you @WiktorStribiżew! The first pattern works like a charm. This is a custom Swift app that crawls a financial document, keeping a list of the mentioned symbols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
[A-Z]+(?=\))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9mZCH7/2).

*Details*:

- `[A-Z]+` - one or more uppercase ASCII letters
- `(?=\))` - a positive lookahead that matches a location that is immediately followed with a `)` char.

Alternatively, you can use the following to capture the values into Group 1:

```
\((?:[^():]*:)?([A-Z]+)\)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DqF4OU/2). *Details*:

- `\(` - a `(` char
- `(?:[^():]*:)?` - an optional sequence of any zero or more chars other than `(`, `)` and `:` and then a `:` char
- `([A-Z]+)` - Group 1: one or more uppercase ASCII letters
- `\)` - a `)` char.

Comment: Minor change needed Wiktor: words need to be uppercase, or else it picks false-positives https://regex101.com/r/DqF4OU/1. Thanks!

Comment: @titusmagnus Maybe `\((?:[^():]*:)?([A-Z]+)\)` then? Or `[A-Z]+(?=\))`.

Comment: Just found another edge-case: `PayPal ( PYPL -2.72% )`  How do I recognize `PYPL` in this case? (https://regex101.com/r/l9RhSv/1). Again, thanks so much for the help!

Comment: @titusmagnus `[A-Z]+(?=(?:\s*[-+]?\d*\.?\d+\s?%?\s*)?\))`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/l9RhSv/2).